# Capitalize the "s" in the search button

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

It's not that big of a deal, but if you look on the search page: https://stackoverflow.com/search the "s" in Search isn't capitalized, and it looks a bit weird since the other button with the same styling "Ask Question" is capitalized properly.

[image]

Comment: So you want a [Giant S](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)?

Comment: Circling has never been fancier.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm why do you think this is tagged [feature-request]?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm What about a [Cool S](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/169045/draw-the-cool-s) ?

Comment: _Not that big of a deal_? My whole SO experience is ruined :(

Comment: That has to be the most elegant freehand circle I have seen in quite some time.

Comment: @Andras https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/38765

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: I want [that S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_logo#/media/File:Superman_shield.svg)!

Comment: You are lukcy it is not [that kind of s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) (*The Many Memes of Meta*).

Comment: I think ask question should be lowercase

Comment: @AndrewGrimm yes, which is why one wouldn't file a _bug_, but rather a feature-request, as the above. Anyway...

Comment: [Spin-off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371479/what-is-sos-style-guide-for-buttons).

Comment: Where are you even seeing this page? Why is it even a page of its own? There is a search bar with an icon at the top of literally every page on the network.

Comment: @TylerH It's stated in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/search Now that you say that, I wonder why that is a separate page

Comment: @SheshankS. interestingly enough, [there is no double search box for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mfTp.png). However visiting it in incognito/inprivate mode shows it. Maybe because I'm part of a team?

Comment: hmm that's interesting, maybe @CalvT

Comment: @TylerH Just asked a question on that, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371498/why-does-https-stackoverflow-com-search-exist

Comment: [Calligraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calligraphy) is freehand writing, so it's technically still a red [freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/203888). Well done.

Comment: "seach" with a lower case looks more compact.

Comment: @SheshankS. Yeah, I meant more how are you *navigating* to that page. As far as I can tell there are no links on the site that direct you to that page... ostensibly *because* there's already a search bar at the top of every page on the network (including on the /search page!)

Comment: I suggest to change to "DOWNLOAD"

Comment: Am I the only one who checked https://stackoverflow.com/Search

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I prefer StackOverflow.com/Search personally

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont not now that you posted the link to make it easier on me

Comment: Oh I see @TylerH

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont. You are GOD for TylerH and CalvT

Comment: That UI is so bad.. yet everyone focuses on an uncapitalized word

Comment: WHere is the textbox and button they are both gone now.

Comment: Looks fixed for me (on rev 2018.7.25.31170)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aaron fixed this last night, as Sheshank S has observed.

Being an incorrigible CSS wrangler at heart, Aaron did *not* fix this by thrashing the button with a giant S; the text served is still very much lowercase. Instead, he applied the following style:

```
text-transform: capitalize !important;
```

Comment: *cry* so i guess no giant S for me ;(

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: They have fixed this, well atleast on my computer...**

[image]

No clue why this didn't get status-completed but okay. They also fixed  the alignment, the page  looks much better now