# What is SO's style guide for buttons?

Tags: support, user-interface, writing-style

I notice that some buttons have their text in title case:

[image]

(Or maybe every word is capitalised rather than title case being used.)

Some are surely faulty, as noted in [Capitalize the “s” in the search button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371464/1115360) (*this one has now been fixed*):

[image]

While others take a mixed approach (this is from SO's [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for users new to the site):

[image]

But wait! There's more! We have...

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net]

and yet:

[image]

Is there an actual style guide which states how the text in buttons must be cased, so that if we spot something we think is in error we can consult the guide to determine if we should alert SO to the problem? If so, can we see it please?

Comment: It's decided case by case ...

Comment: ... but only in this case.

Comment: it's *random* ...

Comment: It's YOLO......!

Comment: It's non existent?

Comment: This is also an issue on SO en español - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olE02.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K5Iz.png) (as well as elsewhere)

Comment: Even the Stacks library documentation can't make it's mind up https://stackoverflow.design/components/buttons  "**A**sk **q**uestion" "**P**ost **A**nswer"

Comment: Buttons of all shapes and sizes are included for diversity.

Comment: To me it looks like proper sentences are *Rendered like this* while pseudo-sentences *Are Not*. Then `Help Center` is a proper noun and thus *Properly Capitalized*. Single words are just like *Pseudo-sentences* except *search* which looks like the only bug.

Comment: I hate answering in comments but the answer is: It doesn't exist or no one follows it.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta "Post Your Answer" and "Add Another Answer" can both be found on question pages. Neither of those fit your hypothesis.

Comment: "It's important to make all buttons feel welcome. We at SO have been working hard to ensure all buttons can feel at home in our community"

Comment: is any0ne feeling Slightly bothereD yeT?

Comment: @MacroMan No I Am Not Feeling Bothered At All. In FaCt I wOuLd lIkE tO cOnTiNuE wRiTiNg lIkE tHiS. 35P3C147Y 1f 1 C4N W7173 L1K3 T415!!10n3!1

Comment: Probably some form of a/B testing

Comment: Everything Will Be Made Uniform In 6 To 8 Weeks.

Comment: Perhaps it is time to welcome pluralisation (and pluralization, if you insist) bug reports?

Comment: What a capital question.

Answer (score 6):

This is something we’re thinking about and codifying now that [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) has [content guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/content/principles). We’re drafting a Grammar & Mechanics section now, and we expect to ship those guidelines soon. The inconsistency is really frustrating.

The TL;DR of our guidance: All calls to action should be in sentence case while respecting certain proper nouns.

Stack Overflow has grown super organically over the years, but with our Stacks team in place, we can start to enforce some consistency in our text strings, especially in new pages, but also in refactors as we fix bugs and such.