# Why does https://stackoverflow.com/search exist?

Tags: discussion, search

Why does the https://stackoverflow.com/search exist? There is a search bar on every page, which basically serves the same purpose.

[image]

I think it should be removed, since it doesn't really help that much. The Search box on top is fairly obvious.

Comment: for one moment I thought you are asking "why does a search bar exist on the site"

Comment: A user walks into a search bar....

Comment: Search exists to find duplicates.

Comment: @TemaniAfif. Thats the reason, you are legend

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It has to exist because that's the page the search takes you to when you search for anything that includes text:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=test

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes%3A5..+created%3A2018-01-01..

If you search for just tags you go here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing+java

But just about anything else takes you to the search page.

Comment: Hm, forgot about that; in this case, going to just stackoverflow.com/search should just redirect you back to where you were (or not load) and say "silly! Just use the search bar above!"

Comment: @TylerH I often do an empty search when I want to get at the Advanced Search Tips. I wouldn't want to have to put something random there just to avoid getting redirected or have it flat out refuse.

Comment: Even better, have all the advanced search tips show in a grey dropdown or sidebar whenever you focus the search field in the topbar, preferably as a child element so clicking/focusing in it would not lose focus on the search bar.