# Capitalisation again

Tags: bug, tags, design, hyperlinks, typographical-error

The "edit tags" link-button has been restyled slightly, and while making that change someone has capitalised it.

This is inconsistent with your other link-buttons (though the actual buttons [tend](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371464/560648) to use title case).

[image: Screenshot of this ghastly fault]

Plz2fix?

Comment: Should be "plz2fix"

Comment: Looks like this is an issue on all sites. Would this be better posted on Meta.SE?

Comment: Capitalists strike again

Comment: @scohe001 Meh, probably

Comment: This qualifies as a capital offense.

Comment: Let's bring this to the Capital

Comment: little things, but they add up

Comment: It's also a sign of poor process if people can just relabel things willy nilly without ensuring they fit within the convention. A trivial example perhaps but how did this get through code review?

Comment: Related: [this answer to "*Inconsistent tooltip capitalisation on question pages*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323796/284827) by [Aaron Shekey ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355163/aaron-shekey)

Answer (score 22):

If, by "fix" you mean make Share/Edit/Follow/Close/Flag capitalised, this is now fixed:

> [image: Screenshot - they're now capitalised]

This is the way things are going - [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323295/capitalized-edit-and-delete-buttons-for-comments-are-inconsistent-with-other#comment1057012_323295) on
[Capitalized “Edit” and “Delete” buttons for comments are inconsistent with other UI elements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323295/284827) (on Meta Stack Exchange) to say:

> I'd rather the post links be updated with capitalization. ;) Capitalized words are becoming the new standard UI here, so I kind of doubt this will be changed back.

[Aaron Shekey ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355163/aaron-shekey) also [replied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323796/284827) to [Inconsistent tooltip capitalisation on question pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323795/284827) (also on Meta Stack Exchange), saying:

> Yep, our capitalization is all over the place. The tricky part is our localization strings for other communities are based on the original English text. This means that if we change "share" to "Share", our translated communities (Russian, Japanese, Spanish, etc.) each have to re-translate.
>
> We'll be making things more consistent as we refactor and modify existing layouts, but that's the interesting technical constraint we're up against.
>
> As to how we intend to capitalize things consistently, that's laid out in our design system called Stacks. https://stackoverflow.design/content/grammar-and-mechanics#use-sentence-casing

Comment: Ew, This Looks Terrible, i Hope They Reconsider :(

Comment: Yes, same here! I like the lowercase links come back.

Comment: This is just awesome. While we can all now see capitalized links, it seems they also changed the structure of the pages, so every curator using user scripts are all very busy fixing those.. and well, not curating :) I think this is what is also called "Busy work" :D

Comment: would be much easier using css, e.g. .`s-btn__link{ text-transform: uppercase;}`. No more translations needed.

Comment: Capitalisation like this looks very ugly. I hope they decide to change back to lower case.

Comment: I like how `add a comment` is still in all lower-case.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: It only looks terrible because you're used to the old way.  Give it about an hour, and you won't even notice it anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to announce such changes somehow (e.g. by featuring this post)? I [wasn't able](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404395/1997232) to find this answer. Btw, please also [fix tooltips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396891/1997232).

Comment: I'm not sure that this change in behaviour solicits making this question [featured] - but it should make its way into the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/284827) FAQ post on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: I gave it over 24 hours, but it still looks terrible. Worse, the absolute positions of these items change, so I can never rely on muscle memory.

Comment: I preferred it when it was lower case. :-( Are we going to capitalise all the tags now, for consistency - `edited 2 days ago`, `answered 2 days ago`, `add a comment`

Answer (score 20):

The odd capitalization is spreading:

[image: When editing a comment, Edit and Delete are now upper case]

Referring to the "Edit tags" text, Shog mentioned in September that after a change, it was ["still with the annoying capitalization"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374211/7795130), but he was told that ["the rest of it is firmly by-design, so... This is probably as completed as it's gonna get."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374061/inline-tag-edit-design-inconsistency/374211#comment631196_374211)

I'm not a fan, but for some reason it seems to be by-design, and it's spreading.

On an unrelated note, if you want to have a shout at another capitalization that doesn't make sense, take a look at the unanswered button.

[image: unanswered is lower case where all the other sort options are upper case.]

Comment: ‍♂️

Answer (score 12):

Just stop this Capitalization Madness [sic] already! Do it everywhere, or, rather, nowhere. This is not a "who moved my cheese"* post fuelled by frustration, pinky swear :)

> [image]

This inconsistency is both annoying and distracting.

* Note the lower case: I hate title case. Don't infer anything from my username—that's PascalCase.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mq0P.png ,does that qualify too?

Comment: Just to add to the distraction: You can only ["edit" your "Watched Tags"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7eOO.png), ["site"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX4WD.png) is the only thing with lowercase on the lower bar. This post from the front page has [votes, answers, views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycHvc.png). Also Stack Overflow is "stackoverflow" in the logo, and STACK OVERFLOW in the lower bar, which always kind of confused me. But I like that "Answer" and "Question" is generally capitalized on the network, as they have special meaning.

Comment: @DragandDrop I might be missing your point, at least what you circled is consistent (not in font), but "Your Answer" also is Incorrectly Capitalized.

Comment: I don't know what correct capitalization is in english. I was trying to "help". Hopefully for Answer I only made it a comment.

Comment: @DragandDrop me neither, but see https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing

Comment: The real problem, of course, is that several of those are bizarre and counter-productive guidelines. Avoid semicolons? Avoid em-dashes? Use sentence casing for *headings*? Ironically, they don't even capitalize "Oxford comma" properly.

Comment: Oh dear lord of footnotes! What is that colon doing after the asterisk? And without a [capital letter to start the footnote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242129/should-the-footnote-be-capitalized)! ;)

Comment: @Andrew I'm honestly very sorry about that, apparently I've never bothered to research what punctuation and capitalization is used in footnotes. Feel free to [edit]!

Comment: Almost as bad as `'s` after a ♥ on a tree.

Comment: @Andrew are you going for the Edit of the Year Award? Because for me, you just won it. And they said we hate fun.

Comment: @CodeCaster Hopefully I have created new problems in the post for someone to enjoy correcting.

Comment: I changed the edit message to contain the intended user name. (cc @AndrewMorton)

Comment: To be honest, @Cody, I thought it was part of the joke, and I thought Andrew backpedaled because of Wai's comment, but thanks!

Comment: Well, you know by now, that's what mods do, we ruin the jokes. I didn't get that at all; I just saw the backpedaling.