# What happened to the tabs in the unanswered page?

Tags: bug, design

I noticed that [the unanswered page](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)'s tab bar looks quite weird:

[image: weird]

This doesn't seem to be the issue of my screen size. I used Safari's Responsive Design Mode to check on larger screen sizes but the all questions button is still on the next line.

I reproduced this on Safari 12.0 and Chrome 72.0.3626.121 running on macOS 10.14.

Comment: I know, it bugs me to no end that "all questions" is the only button who's text isn't capitalized! Oh wait... that's not the issue you're indicating.

Comment: Workaround is to opt-in for the custom question list by the way, once it gets activated on your account the button layout is completely different and much cleaner (IMO, of course).

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Tab border rounding doesn't take wrapping into account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325221/289905). An answer is available there: _“The design of this component will be revisited at some point. Prior to our recent changes that introduce wrapping, horizontal scrolling would be forced. I'd argue this is a much better alternative to that. Our future design will need to be able to wrap without feeling awkward.”_

Comment: @DavyM Now you say it, the "unanswered" tab is not capitalized either, a CSS bug for the last in the list?

Comment: @Kaddath I think it's by design, the last in the list is always the "tab switch" button

Comment: @DavyM Then it should be ALL CAPITALIZED, that's the most important tab! (maybe it knows it and is just humble about it though)

Comment: @Kaddath Oh don't you worry, I complain about that "unanswered" button in [every chance I get!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380064/7795130)

Comment: Is there a reason we're calling these things tabs? They look like buttons. They act like buttons. Are they not buttons?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Functionally, they're effectively tabs: they switch between different views, and indicate which view is currently selected. They also used to be styled in a more tab-like fashion, although that design got replaced with the current row-of-buttons styling a while ago. In any case, on the technical level, they're neither: they're actually just plain old HTML links that are styled to look like buttons (or tabs). The URLs they link to do still use the keyword `tab`, as do some of the CSS class names used to style them.

Comment: Wait, there’s an unanswered question page?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] for me, maybe it was fix or what?