# Inconsistent capitalization of profile titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

If you navigate to your profile, you'll see that the section titles have inconsistent capitalization (for example, Top **M**eta **P**osts vs. Top **n**etwork **p**osts):

[image: Capitalization of titles]

Was this intended behavior?

Comment: Hey, you're supposed to be nice. You effectively just made everyone with OCD go into convulsions.

Comment: I wonder if So Css dev hate us or love us? As we have bug report on capitalisation, 3px marging, inconsitent font. wrong ico.

Comment: [Necessary plug for the "Frequent, Votes, Active, (u)nanswered" bar's capitalization](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380064/7795130)

Comment: There's also *Edit lits* and *View network profile* over the **Top Meta Posts**, which also seem inconsistent

Comment: When a similar situation came up internally between mods and CMs (the "Mod Dashboard" was changed to "Mod dashboard", notice that there is no big D), the reason was because of the usage of Stacks, the new CSS library that SO is using. Stacks apparently forces everything to use a sentence case. My theory here (not a CSS guy): They are moving to Stacks and that apart from the "Top Meta Posts", all others have already been moved. The CSS that "Top Meta Posts" uses, is the old (called primary IIRC) theme, and therefore it is still in title case and not sentence case.

Comment: Sentence case is better because its rules are clearly defined and easy to follow. English is (slowly) going in that direction for titles of things. Or so I've read somewhere. (Conversely, there are various competing standards for Title Case; [Wikipedia currently has this as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Title_case) "defined by rules that are not universally standardised. The standardisation is only at the level of house styles and individual style manuals"; see also [the table there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Lower_case).)