# Please make all of the link tooltips the same style as the "follow" tooltip

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, tooltips, follow-posts

The tooltip on the "follow" link looks great.  Can we have the same style tooltip on the other links, please?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: *"The tooltip on the "follow" link looks great."* No, it looks awful because **it doesn't follow the standard system tooltip scheme**. Don't make all the other tooltips into custom tooltips that look equally different from everything else on my computer. Make the "follow" tooltip look like *all other tooltips*.

Comment: Oh, wow. I hadn't realized that this was a thing that was even implemented - custom tooltips.  Now I can't unsee it.  Worse, it'd be a nightmare to make that work Just Right with different languages.

Comment: It looks like the pop-up being used for the tag links. (At first I thought it might have to do with it being a button but the tag links are regular anchor tags too.)

Comment: Unification of tooltips was [meta-tag:status-deferred] [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/396760#comment769477_396760)

Comment: I personally find "Follow" tooltip visually more appealing. Can we rather standartize other tooltips to be the same as "Follow" one?

Answer (score -4):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. We recognize that time and thought was put into this request, but unfortunately, we can't prioritize it at this time.

Comment: Some of us would like the new tooltips to be transformed to actual tooltips. I avoid Stack Overflow when I don't have my user scripts running. This is one of those reasons.

Comment: Why the status-declined then?

Comment: To note, Anita was a *former* employee.