# Commands under the post and their tooltips

Tags: discussion

Just noticed the commands under posts have now first capital letter. Looks unusual.

Was there an announcement or discussions of this change or do developers believe this doesn't require such steps for such a minor change?

I wanted to report a bug with tooltips, they looks different (Chrome, win64):

[image]

[image]

I personally prefer (like) second one more.

Comment: Related [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404385/11682469).

Comment: As this is network-wide, this is mostly discussed on Meta Stack Exchange, not here: [Capitalization of post action links is causing multiple rows of links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359477/289905), [Tooltips with different styles after a fix was done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359480/289905).

Comment: @Ivar, thought tooltip bug is a new (relevant to change), thanks for finding duplicate.

Comment: @JeanneDark, thanks for finding that post. It would be nice if that answer was somehow announced (for a short time?) to avoid questions like mine.

Comment: @Sinatr Unfortunately, *answers* cannot be featured, only questions. And while that answer is recent, the question it belongs to is 2 years old. It would be confusing to feature it. What *should have happened* is for Stack Exchange to create an announcement and feature that. They've not made one which is saddening. Among other things, this broke some userscripts. I find the lack of any sort of announcement irritating, especially since SE has a bad habit of it and repeatedly reassure us they are trying to improve in that regard.