# No, I don't want to know how review queues work

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, user-interface, banner

I've noticed some excellent UI changes today:

[image: popup]

Yay, review queues, what could those be?

[image: handwave welcome]

Wow, I feel so welcome to /review already.

[image: 3k privilege banner]

I even got access to the Close votes queue! This is the happiest day of my life!

---

Could you please implement a check for a user's rep, or at least completed review tasks? I'm not much of a reviewer but I still have 1100 completed tasks in the CVQ... this is 100% noise to me.

Comment: ..or a count of Steward badges at least :)

Comment: Anyone knowing @AndrasDeak appreciates there's a subtle humoristic end to this post.

Comment: Come on, why would you get rid of this?  It was very helpful because I forgot the first thousand times I reviewed that you review one at a time.

Comment: I must say that in the non-dark version they did nail the look of it, it doesn't look intrusive at all. Actually it looks positively inviting. I did not think it was possible.

Comment: Is the non-dark version the same as the non-non-light?

Comment: And please let the `dialog already shown/viewed` property **not** be stored in a cookie.

Comment: @DaveL17 but then it will keep showing up everytime, even after clicking the x.

Comment: @10Rep What I'm suggesting (admittedly opaquely), is that the setting should be stored on SO.  That way, I don't have to wade through the pop-ups each time I delete my browsing history.

Comment: Could this all have been avoided by simply not clicking on the "learn more" link?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can't not click the "learn more" link because [I'm trying to pass that one hour until capitalization stops bothering me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375683/capitalisation-again/404385#comment818709_404385).

Comment: Humor aside, I sometimes wish that we'd stop talking about bikeshed issues like this one.  It gives corporate the impression that we actually [should] care about these things, when there are more pressing problems to solve first.

Comment: @RobertHarvey we keep being told that _they_ can make pointless UI changes without hindering actual work on the site because UI is a different team so the effort is not spent at the expense of something meaningful. Based on that I don't see why they couldn't change a bad UI decision in said UI team. And I agree this is bikeshedding. But if I go to my favourite park and see that the local bikeshed is now covered in mirrors making the sun shine in my eye, I will complain.

Comment: Fair point .....

Answer (score 15):

The [Network announcement for this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363485/new-onboarding-for-review-queues/) mentions these already:

> We are also showing a popover to users who earned access to review queues in the past, but have never done a review or haven't reviewed in the last 30 days. This popover is only appearing for the next 90 days. The goal is to engage users who may not have interacted with the queues since we made visual design changes and improved communication about suspensions.

You can also dismiss the messages forever by clicking the "dismiss" or "X" button at the top-right.

---

It appears this modal (or popover, as they refer to it in the MSE announcement) is buggy, and will appear for you regardless of whether you've recently reviewed in a respective queue or not.

Comment: Thanks. Is the implication that this is not a bug? It's definitely a mistake. But I can retag this to be a feature request if this is on purpose (ugh).

Comment: I think it is clearly intentional that it appears for everyone, based on the wording in the announcement on MSE. At the very least I would probably consider your post a [meta-tag:feature-request] rather than a [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks for coming clear you had been slacking for at least 30 days. Glad you're back now ....join the force ....

Comment: @rene I may have been slacking a _lot_ longer than 30 days :P

Comment: I'm seeing these popups despite having done some reviews within the past two days: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: @dbc perhaps you get one for each review queue you haven't laboured in for the past 30 days. You know, for good measure.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - I got it for the "Low quality posts" queue which I visit frequently.

Comment: @dbc I believe there is an answer covering this as a bug on the MSE announcement already: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363504/253521

Comment: i have on "my" sinca a long time access to review io simply don't earned the right to vote for close votes now, i have done that month ago, what the....

Comment: @nbk I'm sorry, I don't understand what your comment is saying.

Comment: @TylerH the message says like in the images show you earned the right review close votes, that privilege you earn with 3k rep and not with much more, so the message is intended for users that reach 3k rep, but everybody gets this message, so why the hell did i get this message

Comment: @nbk if you read the announcement it says they are intentionally showing it to everyone since it was just added. They intended to show it only for queues where someone has not reviewed within the last 90 days, but it sounds like a lot of users are getting the notice regardless of how recently they reviewed in that queue.

Comment: this is spam, and shouldn't be shown, to user with more than hundred votes already, what the use, nobody can follow the rules as they change from person to person. depending who reviews the reviews. So the hole thing is a farce, like this message

Comment: _"You can also dismiss the messages forever"_ Except you have to do that for every single site where you have >=500 rep.

Comment: @41686d6564 Technically you can just wait the 90 days until you review again and then you won't have to click on the "X" ;)

Comment: “We are also showing a popover to users who earned access to review queues in the past, but have never done a review or haven't reviewed in the last 30 days.” - I routinely clear every review queue multiple times a day, yet today, I was given a guide to the very review queue that I helped clear yesterday.

Comment: @41686d6564 Having to do it for each site/queue doesn't mean it isn't dismissed forever once you dismiss it.

Answer (score 5):

Strange. The network announcement says that this popover is visible to those who haven't reviewed in the past 30 days.

However, I reviewed 40 posts (and almost cleared) the suggested edits queue just this morning, and this is what I see after going to [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review):

[image]

Is this a bug, or an oversight?

Comment: Is asking a question in the Answer box a "Not an Answer"? :P

Comment: I reported a bug about this here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363510/344280