# Let's have an "Answering a good question well" modal when users "earn it"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, closed-questions, user-interface

Related to [No, I don't want to know how review queues work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406965/2943403), I am also annoyed at the well intentioned popup when I visited the review queue today.

This got me thinking!  This is the perfect annoyance to help with a Meta question that I posted which was heavily downvoted because folks believe it is too invasive to the UX.

Transfer this "helpful" modal to the strategy @ [How to discourage rushed answers on questions that should be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397526/2943403)

When 3 of a user's last 4 answers have been on closed questions, give them this style of annoying alert.

The "Answering a good question well"<sup>([mods-only link](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/a/2599/529))</sup> modal should express how important it is to curate fantastic content by only posting educational/explained answers to unique, clear, complete, on-topic questions.

This "reminder" modal should not exclude anyone based on experience, frequency of posting, unicorn points, etc.  *All* users need to be reminded that not all questions should be answered.

If contributors start looking back at the plethora of great posts over the past 10 years, they can make great improvements in the content and invariably learn some new tricks that they hadn't considered.

Growth trajectory. Everyone wins.

---

Edit: (Here is a fraction of my post from my mod-only link)

> You're about to answer a question and the community appreciates your effort to contribute. To best help the asker and thousands of researchers in the future, we've provided some guidance:
>
> Before you post, see if the question should be answered.
>
> - **Read the entire question.** If the question is unclear or incomplete, is a duplicate of another question on this site, or should be closed for any reason indicated by /help/on-topic, please flag/vote to close the question instead.  *Closing unsuitable questions helps this site to maintain clean and valuable content.
> - **Read all of the comments under the question.** If another user has suggested a duplicate page, please compare the earlier posted page with this page.  If the earlier page suitably answers the question, please support the volunteer's flag/vote to close the current question instead of answering.  If you would like to add a new valuable answer, please post on the earlier question. *Closing duplicate questions helps askers to find solutions without creating new/unnecessary content.*
> - **Read all of the existing answers on the page.** If your advice already exists in another answer, please do not post a duplicate answer as a way of supporting a particular technique.  *Duplicate answers do not add value to this site; in fact, they waste researchers' time ...consider how long it took you to read all of the answers.*
>
> When you post, be specific and generous about your advice with the intent to educate the asker and thousands of future researchers that may not yet have a full understanding of the concepts/techniques involved.  *Explaining your solution is far more valuable than a "Try this" answer.*

I am very flexible about the algorithm which triggers this requested feature as well as the actual text which is offered in the modal itself.

Comment: The alerts could make users stop answering bad questions, or make them try to get bad questions reopened.

Comment: Much harder to get bad questions reopened as a solitary player.  They might even bother to improve salvagable questions.  Imagine if answerers start caring about question quality!

Comment: There are two things I am wondering: Would this apply to *all* close reasons, or are some excluded? Duplicates seem like a grey area. Also, "3 of a user's last 4" might miss rapid answerers – how about something like "75% of last day's answers"?

Comment: Sure, I'm very flexible on the algorithm.  I don't see dupes as grey.  If an answer gets the prompt and go "What!" then they might go back and review their recent answers in some cases they may help to campaign for an inappropriately closed question (where low rep askers may feel powerless).  Improving awareness is good.

Comment: Good idea but I think the scope is too small

Comment: I am happy to hear answers that will build on the notion. @Dharman

Comment: I think the question would be improved by including a screenshot of the content on the mods-only link (since it is probably just a modal/generic message, not some sensitive content). There is not much benefit to linking to mod-only content in a post on Meta... the audience is exceedingly small.

Comment: I generally agree with this proposal, but, i see very little chance of it ever occurring. There appears to be very little interest these days in optimizing for pearls, and instead much interest in increasing user engagement/happiness which tends to instead favor every question getting an answer regardless of quality or how many times it's been asked.

Comment: This modal might prevent high rep people from posting an answer, but it likely won't give much pause to people who insist on posting their "bad" answers. I mean, the only difference between a good and bad answer on Meta is popularity, not it's intention or even content. Even well reasoned and researched answers and questions get heavily downvoted, due to the prevalence of opposing opinions. I've gotten heavily DVed on regular sites with answers that actually fixed my problem, simply because people didn't like it, understand it, or apparently believe it worked. A modal isn't going to fix that.

Comment: I feel like this would shift the ["Fast Gun in the West"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308302/2191572) problem from being caused solely by answer competition to now include FOMO for not being able to answer a crap question fast enough.

Comment: If the intention is to allow only "good" questions on the site, why do we allow attributed public posts at all? If someone could be punished or admonished for answering a question that is subsequently closed are we not already in the mode that all questions should be privately moderated and approved prior to being posted? Should all answers be likewise hidden until gatekeepers have approved the question?

Comment: @JonSG if the "gatekeepers" are answerers/curators/voters, we're already in such a scenario. The issue this would attempt to address is "gatekeepers" allowing things to flourish that other "gatekeepers" have deemed inappropriate or not up to par with the quality of content we want this site to promote. One isn't necessarily more correct than the other.

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem this would solve. Is the purpose to discourage people from posting bad Questions? Or to get respondents to direct their energy to good questions? Or to entice people to improve questions? Or to drive bad questions to closure? Annoying popups do not seem like an optimal approach to any of these goals.

Comment: @TylerH the content is from the Moderator Team which is not permitted to be shared publicly.

Comment: @Catija Only sensitive/embargoed content should be considered under the policy. I'm not seeing how there could be content shared there that is useful to include here but wouldn't be OK with posting. A random mockup by a moderator should not an issue.

Comment: @TylerH Since (in this case) the content of the link is mickmackusa's own work, he can recreate it here, sure... if it were created by another mod, though, he'd have to at least get the permission to reuse it. But I'd specifically recommend actually copy & pasting the content rather than a screenshot. But the rules have always been relatively strict that the content of the TL and the Team are private.

Comment: @Catija how would you like the mod link to be resolved?  Would you like to scrub it from the history?  I can later add my _overly-wordy suggestion of what the modal might say_ to this page statically.

Comment: The link is totally not an issue - the Mod Team isn't a secret and no one can access it without being a member - you can just remove it manually if you're editing to actually include the example text you drafted. No need to redact or anything.

Comment: @Catija "if it were created by another mod, though, he'd have to at least get the permission to reuse it." Is content in the moderator zone not [Subscriber Content](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing)?

Comment: @Peilonrayz That terms of service applies to the public sites only. Teams are not public network sites - they are private sites. That said, this isn't a matter of ToS - it's a matter of privacy. Things said on the Team are private and are understood to be so. It is completely inappropriate to move that content out of a private space without permission, just as a matter of trust.

Comment: @Catija I was just wondering if the _license_ gave permission.

Comment: @Peilonrayz It's either irrelevant or I'm completely misunderstanding what you're asking. That license does not apply to Teams at all. The group/company/entity that owns a Team gets to set the licensing and export rules for that Team.

Comment: While I strongly support measures to increase the number of questions closed as duplicates, I think this proposal is unlikely to work. It will take about 5 seconds to write a user script to suppress the modal and the fastest guns in the <insert cardinal direction here> will just keep on shooting. New answerers desperate for reputation will just ignore it.

Comment: @IanCampbell then I am happy to institute a secondary layer based on my first (linked) question.  If we have people that are serial offenders of answering closable questions than I don't think we need to apologize for dampening their UX while they add noise to this site.  Sort of a "sorry, not sorry" moment.

Comment: *how important it is to curate fantastic content by only posting educational/explained answers to unique, clear, complete, on-topic questions* - which is massively at odds with such a user pair's "I just need an answer now, and I'm fully prepared to put in the bare minimum necessary to get some FGITW to score their FIPs by doing it for me"/"I just need to scab out an answer as fast as possible to get my FIPs"

Comment: @Caius I agree with you (I think?) I don't mind interrupting the UX for these types of users -- they are `#HereToHelpMyself` instead of `HereToHelpSO`. If SO is not going to take steps to better manage the slop that continues to surge in, then I must ask myself why I devote so much time to the lost cause that is curation.

Answer (score 2):

I dont like this at all.

When you close a question, people can no longer answer it, so your solution only
helps in the time between the question being posted, and the question being
closed.

If these questions are truly as bad as you say, then that amount of time should
be small. When you kill the question, you in essence kill the answers too, so
I think any focus should be more on ideas like "how do we encourage good
questions" or "how do we discourage bad questions".

To respond to comment: if someone upvotes an answer, its because they were
helped by it, or they think its a good answer. So if someone want to put a good
answer, on a crap question, and one or more people think its a good enough
answer to deserve an upvote, I really dont see anything wrong with that.

Again, I dont think we need to be discouraging people submitting answers, even
answers on crappy questions. Remember, without good answers, this site is
pointless. Now **bad answers**, of course thats another thing. But you cant know
an answer is bad just based on the question, which is why again I think this is
a bad idea. Here is a link that provides some historical context to "help
vampires", which I think is at the core of the issue here, not people answering
questions:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077

Comment: I mean, if you go this argument, you then have to accept that these Q&A should be deleted to have any semblance of disincentive. But, users whining on meta about their answer being deleted, and users with high reputation taking their side, quality takes a hike usually in such events.

Comment: Well, if you see nothing wrong with it, I refer to Yahoo Answers and rest my case.

Comment: "_your solution only helps in the time between the question being posted_"  No, you misunderstand the intent of my feature request.  If a 3 out of 4 of an user's answers are currently closed (for any reason and not yet deleted), then they will get the reminder.  It doesn't matter if they are a FGITW poster. With over [21M Q's and 31M A's built up over more than a decade](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), the simple fact is that the majority of all new questions are duplicates or off-topic for some reason. (...and people wonder why getting upvotes are so hard to earn on new Qs!)

Comment: Oh, I judge answers too.  I just judge the questions first.  SO provides virtually no guidance to its users regarding the importance of question closure as part of curating terrific content.  Curators are overwhelmed with the amount of unwanted content here.  There are many SMEs that could be putting more effort into providing awesome answers if they were so distracted with handling wave after wave of duplicate/off-topic questions.  Stack Overflow benefits when the community lifts its game.

Comment: I want more people to care.  People cannot care until they become aware.  I commented to an answerer yesterday to ask for help with closing duplicate questions (after I hammered the question) and they said that they have been a registered user for more than 10 years, but didn't know _how_ to close a page!  Awareness first.  Without better curation, SO cannot truly become the "researchers' paradise" that it is designed to be.

Comment: The reasoning here does not match what I see in high-frequency tags. Even clearly typo or unreproducible questions easily garner 2-3 answers before enough people CV. Similarly, I feel this suggestion fits "how do we discourage bad questions" - bad questions are asked *because they get answered*. Putting good answers on bad questions is just more of a signal that bad questions are okay.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "bad questions are asked because they get answered". Can you give any evidence for that? It could easily be that Stack Overflow has made a reputation as the place to go if one wants to ask a computer Question, so that's what people do.

Comment: @Scratte I think it's obvious that I cannot give "evidence", for the simple reason that there cannot *be* evidence of random people's motivation. At the same time, I would be really interested what you think "reputation as the place to go if one wants to ask a computer Question" could possibly mean – surely not much else than asking a question *to get an answer*, no?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What I'm saying is that there's no evidence for your claim that "bad questions are asked **because** they get answered". As you have no evidence, you don't know if that is the reason. You can't know if anyone will stop asking if none of them are answered. The body of worldwide users is not a homogeneous group. I'm going to guess that most users that asks a Question are surprised by the reception they get, which would indicate other reasons why they ask. Like the Big Blue Button and years of trying to get users to push it.

Comment: @Scratte Alright, so should we now reject my and your (very valid) guess because there is no evidence? I *have* seen tons of askers skirt headlong into the q-ban because they *did* go on asking after they *did* get answers. I *have* seen tons of people being surprised their new question isn't appropriate citing that <random similar bad question X> got so nice answers. But I could not possibly produce *evidence* for it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Perhaps we could just acknowledge that they are guesses and not present them as facts. There are also users that don't get any Answers and still keep trying. Perhaps there are also users, that try once and never return, and there's no shortage of people in the world. I had been using Stack Overflow for years before I joined. I thought it was the place to ask Questions. I had no idea that Stack is the worst place to do that until I had already been a member for months and actively reading meta.

Comment: @Scratte What parts after "what I see in high-frequency tags" suggested my comment was anything but my personal impressions from the limited subset of SO that I see? In case it's not clear, I am rather irritated by being drilled as much to present evidence for something that is my personal impression, or the implication that I would not be willing to acknowledge my "guesses", as you put it, as such.